# What (in the world) is well-conditioned vs. low rank fat-tail singular profile?

Tags: linear-regression, linear-algebra

Scikit learn has a `make_regression` data generator.  Can someone *explain it to me like I'm 5* what is meant in the [help docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html#sklearn.datasets.make_regression) by "The input set can either be well conditioned (by default) or have a low rank-fat tail singular profile"?

Answer (score 0):

Well-conditioned: the data is well formatted for the regression task.

Low rank: the input has low dimensional data.

Fat tail: the dataset has a lot of extreme values, which could be challenging as the distribution is unbalanced.

Singular profile: specific distribution.

On a whole, make_regression is able to make many kinds of random regressions problems, from simple distributions (well-conditioned) to very complex ones (singular).